# Angular Multipe tab content into one PDF using jsPDF and html2canvas

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using angular 5 and i want to create a pdf of different tab into one PDF. I tried using jsPDF but the only active div tab contents are getting stored and for another div with differnt ID it is giving below error.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData

Please let me know whether this is achievable.

Thanks
vinod.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html2pdf like this:

First you need to npm install it

```
npm i html2pdf.js --save
```

then import it in your component:

```
import * as html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';
```

Second you use it like this:

```
let content = `some html`;

const opt = {
  margin: 1,
  filename: 'pdf_Name.pdf',
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
  html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};

// Save the PDF
html2pdf().set(opt).from(content).save();
```

Comment: Thanks. html content is of different tabs and i am not able to combine all the div. if i put the div on the top of all tab then only tab is appearing and not the contents.